# javascript: which functions are called on an object during indexing?

Tags: javascript, indexing, for-loop, mshtml

This might be a poorly worded question but considering this snippet:

```
var foo = { bar : 1 };
var bar = foo['bar'];
```

What functions are actually called when indexing into foo? Similarly, what if you had the following code:

```
var foo = { bar : 1 };
for(var x in foo)
   dosomething();
```

What functions on foo would actually be called in the for statement? Suppose I wanted to change the behavior for both of these scenarios for a given object, how would I do that?

To be more specific what I'm actually doing is passing a .net object into an MSHTML document (foo above would be the object in reality), the object implements IReflect and during an index call (like scenario 1 above) calls to GetProperties and GetFields are made. I need to know which property it's looking for so I can implement it and have it call my object.

Comment: There are no JavaScript functions called as a result of property lookup on an object. Are you asking about implementation-specific methods for a particular JS interpreter?

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that. I might be asking for implementation specific methods but I was hoping that there were corresponding functions for these operations. That would have been convenient. Then I suppose my real question is how can I do indexing for IReflect objects...

Comment: Turns out you have to actually create the 'val' property on the clr object! I was expecting the call into InvokeMember to give me some type of indexer call but it was actually translating the indexing into a call to the property... still trying to figure out enumerating in the for though.

Comment: Ugh, just realized an array has properties named 0, 1, 2... which aren't legal property names for clr objects so this might be tricky.

Comment: If you need more custom stuff like this you might be better off by implementing a class of your own (Hash or something) and providing some nice method (myHash.each) to iterate/etc.

Comment: That's not a bad idea except that the each function would still have to return something enumerable. I managed to get the objects to return members with numbers for their names by created a class that inherits from PropertyInfo. Then the js runtime will call back asking for a member of that name. Which I parse into an int and translate into an indexer call. The only thing I'm still stumped on is this darn for..in problem.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same level, I implemented a simple example of each for you, https://gist.github.com/764494 . It's pretty versatile pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to the first part is to create your own PropertyInfo objects named after the indexes of items in your collection and return them . I still haven't figured out how to be compatible with for..in however.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are looking for magic getters and setters like in PHP.
John Resig [wrote an article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) about that. It doesn't work on all platforms though.

Comment: I think the concept is very similar. I think that IReflect is very similar in purpose but for clr objects.